# How to make a working hyperlink with more than 255 characters in CONCATENATE() Excel function?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, char, concatenation, limit

I have a `URL` that exceeds max char limit to hyperlink it,
and also I use `CONCATENATE()` function to split the `URL` in 3 parts.
Basically it looks like **`=HYPERLINK( CONCATENATE( A1; A2; A3 ) )`**

How can I fix the **`#VALUE!`** message and make the link workable?

Answer (score 0):

Just try `=Hyperlink(A1&A2&A3,"Link")`.

Comment: i keep having the same issue, so what i understand that total count of characters in all cells should not exceed the max limit. Thats why your answer is not helping @BruceWayne